# Read file into Array in JavaFX then write back

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, file-read

I'm working on a little inventory program and am trying to determine how to get the data from a file into any array of some sort so I can bind the data to some controls. The idea is that the user can navigate through the data and make changes, which will then be written back into the file (overwriting what's presently in it).

This is a javafx program. I read in the data just fine, but everything I've tried so far doesn't make the data accessible outside of the while loop. Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful. So far I've had no joy with ArrayList, or an Array of Objects as there just doesn't seem to anywhere to put that I can access after I've read in all the information.

```
try (
            ObjectInputStream read_file = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("stock.dat")) ;
            ) {
        while (true) {

            String invItemName = read_file.readUTF() ;
            double itemCost = read_file.readDouble() ;
            double itemPrice = read_file.readDouble() ;
            double itemStartInv = read_file.readDouble() ;
            double itemUnitsSold = read_file.readDouble() ;
            double itemProjectedSales = read_file.readDouble() ;
            double profit = ((itemPrice - itemCost) * itemUnitsSold) ;
            //double dblActualvsProjectedSalesPercentage = getSalesPercentage(itemUnitsSold, itemProjectedSales) ;
            double dblDefaultOrder = itemProjectedSales + (itemProjectedSales * .1) ;
            double dblBigOrder = dblDefaultOrder + (dblDefaultOrder * .1) ; 

            InventoryItem o = new InventoryItem(invItemName, itemCost, itemPrice, itemStartInv, itemUnitsSold, itemProjectedSales);

            //For each line in the file, format & display in the primary inventory window
            taCurrentInventory.appendText(String.format( "Item: \t\t\t%8s\nUnit Cost: \t\t\t$%.2f\nUnit Price: \t\t\t$%.2f\nBeginning Inventory: \t%.0f\nUnits Sold: \t\t\t%.0f\nEstimated Sales: \t\t%2.0f\n------------------------------------\n", invItemName, itemCost, itemPrice, 
                   itemStartInv, itemUnitsSold, itemProjectedSales ));

            //Fill in taSalesAndProfit with sales firgures
            taSalesAndProfit.appendText(String.format( "Item: \t%s\nSales: \t%.0f\nProfit: \t$%.2f\n-----------------------------\n", invItemName, itemUnitsSold, profit ) ) ;

            //Format and display our profit data
            if (o.getActualvsProjectedSalesPercent(itemUnitsSold, itemProjectedSales) >= 20 || o.getActualvsProjectedSalesPercent(itemUnitsSold, o.getEstSales()) >= -19) { //Just dispay if actual sales vs projected sales percentage is down less than 20%
                taMarketing.appendText(String.format( "%s \t %4.0f%%\n", invItemName, o.getActualvsProjectedSalesPercent(itemUnitsSold, o.getEstSales()) ) ) ;
            }
            else { //Flag item for a sales promotion to get rid of excess inventory because actual sales vs projected sales are down 20% or more
                taMarketing.appendText(String.format( "%s \t %4.0f%% - Sale!!\n", invItemName, o.getActualvsProjectedSalesPercent(itemUnitsSold, o.getEstSales()) ) ) ;    
            }

            //Format and display our ordering needs
            if (o.getActualvsProjectedSalesPercent(itemUnitsSold, itemProjectedSales) >= 20) { //If sales are 20% or more than projected order 10% more than usual
                taOrdering.appendText(String.format("Item: \t\t%s\nOrder Qty: \t%.0f\n---------------------------\n", invItemName, dblBigOrder)) ;                    
            }
            else { //Otherwise, just order the usual +10% of projected sales
                taOrdering.appendText(String.format("Item: \t\t%s\nOrder Qty: \t%.0f\n---------------------------\n", invItemName, dblDefaultOrder)) ;
            }

        }

    }
    catch (EOFException ex) {

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace() ;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or exceptions? If yes, please show the stack trace,

Comment: No errors, I'm just trying to figure out how/where to put the data so I can access all the product information, so it can be updated and saved back into the file.

Comment: Wow that's ugly. This is a file created by object serialization, I assume. It is good practice to have only one object per file - so you should either create a class that aggregates all your data and serialize an instance of it, or you should serialize an instance of a `Collection` class. If you do that, you can just read the object back and put it into a reference, then access whatever you need from it.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing `ta*` are text areas? This means you have your data access code intertwined with your view (UI) code. You should separate those into difference classes: have a data access class that gets the data and returns a reference to it, and your view class should present the data that's retrieved.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have an example a data access class, would you?